# making a long cell in another row in PDF

Tags: itext

I have an iTextSharp Table with 5 columns. After each row of 5 cells I want to add another cell in another row with only one column (since the length of this cell is too long).

I tried to add 6th cell but the layout is not what I want,

It is like:
first row: the 5 cells of record 1
second row :the 6th cell of record 1
then line(BORDER)
3th row: the 5 cells of record 2
4th row :the 6th cell of record 2
  and here is my code

```
it.Font tableCellFont = new it.Font(testBaseFont, 7, it.Font.NORMAL, it.Color.BLACK);
it.Font tableCellBoldFont = new it.Font(testBaseFont, 7, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK);
it.Font tableHeaderFont = new it.Font(testBaseFont, 8, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK);

//Create new PDF document
it.Document doc = new it.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
it.Phrase p = new it.Phrase("item1", new it.Font(testBaseFont, 14, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK));
p = new it.Phrase("item2", new it.Font(testBaseFont, 14, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK));
p.Leading = 2;
doc.Add(p);

it.Table logTable = new it.Table(5);
logTable.Alignment = it.Table.ALIGN_LEFT;
logTable.DefaultVerticalAlignment = it.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
logTable.Width = 100;
logTable.Border = it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
logTable.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
logTable.DefaultCellBorder = it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
logTable.Cellspacing = 2;
logTable.Cellpadding = 0;
logTable.DefaultCellBackgroundColor = it.Color.WHITE;
//logTable.SetWidths(new int[] { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 });
//Write column headers
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Name", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Country", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("City", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Job", tableHeaderFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Age", tableHeaderFont));

logTable.AddCell(new it.Cell(new it.Phrase("Martin", tableCellFont)));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Italy", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Torino", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Software developer", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("29", tableCellFont));
//here I'd like to insert a row


logTable.AddCell(new it.Cell(new it.Phrase("Jack", tableCellFont)));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("U.S.A", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("New York", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("Manager", tableCellFont));
logTable.AddCell(new it.Phrase("50", tableCellFont));

//here I'd like to insert a row

doc.Add(logTable);
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I have to put the same warning in as your previous question for future readers.)*

`Table` is no longer support nor is the version of iTextSharp that you are using, you should switch to `PdfPTable` instead.

However, what you want to do is set the `ColSpan` on your cell that you want to cross multiple columns.

```
var t = new iTextSharp.text.Table(5);
t.AddCell("A");
t.AddCell("B");
t.AddCell("C");
t.AddCell("D");
t.AddCell("E");

t.AddCell(new Cell("This is my long text") { Colspan = 5 });
```

Or, if you're using an older version of C#:

```
var c = new Cell("This is my long text");
c.Colspan = 5;
t.AddCell(c);
```

**EDIT**

To change the borders, the easiest thing to do is just change the `DefaultCell` properties when needed.

```
//Turn off borders
t.DefaultCell.Border = Table.NO_BORDER;
t.AddCell("A");
t.AddCell("B");
t.AddCell("C");
t.AddCell("D");
t.AddCell("E");

//Turn bottom borders on
t.DefaultCell.Border = Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
t.AddCell(new Cell("This is my long text") { Colspan = 5 });

//Turn borders off again
t.DefaultCell.Border = Table.NO_BORDER;
t.AddCell("F");
t.AddCell("G");
t.AddCell("H");
t.AddCell("I");
t.AddCell("J");
```

Comment: hi .thank u very much for ur kindness reply.yes, i will report to my colleagues. my current task is to add something to the code which is made by another programmer many years ago.

Comment: hi. thank u very much again.but now i've found for row with cell(A,B,C,D ,E) and row "This is my long text".there is a border too. my task is ,between cell(A,B,C,D ,E) and row "This is my long text",there is no border. then there is a border(a line),then another cell(A,B,C,D ,E) and row "This is my long text". i dont know for itextsharp i can add a "cell" of whole line? thank u very much again

Comment: is it possible to do sth like  logTable.AddCell(new it.Cell(new it.Phrase(it.BORDER, tableCellFont)){ Colspan = 5 })? thank u very much

Comment: unfortunately no. there is nothing. but if i delete the code  logTable.DefaultCellBorder = 0;, ifound on  the first line(where there is field name )there is strange border

Comment: i think i'd better also add a little configuration code: it.Table logTable = new it.Table(4);logTable.Alignment = it.Table.ALIGN_LEFT;
 logTable.DefaultVerticalAlignment = it.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;logTable.Width = 100;  logTable.Border = it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                logTable.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
                logTable.DefaultCellBorder = 0;// it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;          logTable.Cellspacing = 2;logTable.Cellpadding = 0;
  logTable.DefaultCellBackgroundColor = it.Color.WHITE;
 logTable.SetWidths(new int[] { 20, 20, 45, 15 });

Comment: i did in this way and it works. thank u very much from heart    logTable.Border = it.Table.TOP_BORDER | it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;
   logTable.DefaultCell.Border = it.Table.TOP_BORDER;
             ................
                    logTable.DefaultCell.Border = it.Table.NO_BORDER;//.BOTTOM_BORDER;     
     ...............
                  logTable.DefaultCell.Border = it.Table.BOTTOM_BORDER;